# MVC Cascading dropdownlist not populating the second dropdown using Jquery

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller

I have been struggling with this issue for a whole 2 hours now, I do not know what is going wrong, I have a created a MVC project, added a model with options to select, when the first item is selected out need to populated the second drop-down. The code seems to work fine although nothing is being populated in the second drop-down and I do get a 200 Ok response. Please see coed below.

Controller code:

```
public ActionResult Register()
{
    List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>() {
        new SelectListItem(){ Value="1", Text="Microsoft"},
        new SelectListItem(){ Value="2", Text="Apple"},
        new SelectListItem(){ Value="3", Text="Others"}
    };

    RegisterViewModel programming = new RegisterViewModel();
    programming.types = new SelectList(list, "Value", "Text");
    programming.languanges = new SelectList(new List<SelectListItem>(), "Value", "Text");

    return View(programming);
}

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetLanguages(string typeSelected)
{
    int type = int.Parse(typeSelected);
    List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();

    if (type == 1)
    {
        list.AddRange(new List<SelectListItem>()
        {
            new SelectListItem(){ Value="3", Text="Asp"},
            new SelectListItem(){ Value="4", Text="BASIC"},
            ....
        });
    }
    else if (type == 2)
    {
        list.AddRange(new List<SelectListItem>()
        {
            new SelectListItem(){ Value="2", Text="AppleScript"},
        });
    }
    else
    {
        list.AddRange(new List<SelectListItem>()
        {
            new SelectListItem(){ Value="1", Text="ActionScript"},
            new SelectListItem(){ Value="7", Text="Clojure"},
            ....
        });
    }

    RegisterViewModel programming = new RegisterViewModel();
    programming.languanges = new SelectList(list, "Value", "Text");

    return Json(new { programming.languanges });
}
```

Here is my htmkl dropdown definition

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("Software Company", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.selectedType, Model.types, "--Select a type--")
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("Software Created By this company", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
   <div class="col-md-10">
       @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.selectedLanguange, Model.languanges, "--Select a language--")
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is my script for the call to the action controller method

```
$(function () {
    $('#selectedType').change(function () {
        debugger;
        var typeSelected = $('#selectedType :selected').val();
        typeSelected = typeSelected == "" ? 0 : typeSelected;
        //When select 'optionLabel' we need to reset it to default as well. So not need 
        //travel back to server.
        if (typeSelected == "") {
            $('#selectedLanguange').empty();
            $('#selectedLanguange').append('<option value="">--Select a language--</option>');
            return;
        }

        //This is where the dropdownlist cascading main function
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "GetLanguages",                            //Your Action name in the DropDownListConstroller.cs
            data: "{'typeSelected':" + typeSelected + "}",  //Parameter in this function, Is cast sensitive and also type must be string
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json"

        }).done(function (data) {
            //When succeeded get data from server construct the dropdownlist here.
            if (data != null) {

                $('#selectedLanguange').empty();
                $.each(data.languanges, function (index, data) {
                    $('#selectedLanguange').append('<option value="' + data.Value + '">' + data.Text + '</option>');
                });
            }
        }).fail(function (response) {
            if (response.status != 0) {
                alert(response.status + " " + response.statusText);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The script fails and returns a 200 OK. Please assist.

Comment: When you debug, where specifically does this fail?  Does the `change` event invoke the JavaScript code?  Is the AJAX request made?  Does it have the data you expect?  What is the server's response?  Does it have the data you expect?  Is the callback handler in the JavaScript executing?  Debug.

Comment: From your code you are returning `programming.languages` where as in js also you are trying to access `data.languages`, try to return `programming` from .cs code.

Comment: Creating an identical `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` from the first one using `new SelectList(...)` is ridiculous, as is serializing `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` (just send back a collection of anonymous objects). And `typeSelected = typeSelected == "" ? 0 : typeSelected;` means the following line `if (typeSelected == "") {` will always be false and that code will never be executed. And its just `data: { typeSelected: typeSelected  },` and delete the `contentType` option.

Comment: And the method should be `public JsonResult GetLanguages(int typeSelected)` since you expect an `int` and it should be just `return Json(list);`. There is a lot of code here that makes little sense and you will never get correct 2-way model binding or validation, particularly if editing existing data or you need to return the view.. Suggest you study the code in this [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym)